# How to use PHPMailer only for checking login password?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, phpmailer

I want to use `PHPMailer` to send email. However, the first step I only want to check whether user's password is correct. If it is correct, next step is to notice user to write receiver's email address. For example:

```
<?php
include('snail_database.txt');
require_once('/var/www/PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php'); 
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail -> CharSet='utf-8'; 

$mail -> IsSMTP(); 
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail -> Host = $server; 
$mail -> Port = 25; 
$mail -> From = 'try@snail.duckdns.org'; 
$mail -> FromName = 'try'; 
$mail -> Username = 'try'; 
$mail -> Password = 'try';  
//then check whether this password and email addresses correct without sending email to others. 
//Which function can be used to check this only?
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, update your PHPMailer - you are using a very old version.

You can't do this with PHPMailer itself, but you can use the SMTP class it comes with. In the examples folder you will find [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps) that shows how you can drive the SMTP class. It doesn't quite go as far as you need, but you will get the basic idea of how to send commands and read responses. If you look at PHPMailer's code from [this point](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L1427), that should be enough to get you going.